# Best Practice for querying data from foreign table in Rails API for React

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, activerecord, axios

So I am building a web app with a Rails backend and a React frontend.

on my `meals#index` page, I want to display all my meals but also the name and address of the restaurant they are associated to (a meal `belongs_to` a restaurant and a restaurant `has_many` meals).

I a classic Rails app I would simply write:

```
<%= meal.restaurant.name %>
<%= meal.restaurant.address %>
```

and the query happens behind the scenes.

But in the case of a React/Rails app, I need to fetch all that data from the controller.

so how can I turn my index method:

```
module Api::V1
  class MealsController < ApplicationController
    def index
      @meals = Meal.order(:id)
      render json: @meals
    end
  end
end
```

So that it fetches the restaurants data (of-course as fast as possible).

btw I use axios for fetching data from rails to react:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('api/v1/meals.json')
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
        this.setState({
            meals: response.data
        })
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to `include` the *meal's restaurant* in the `json` response itself like so

```
render json: @meals.to_json(include: :restaurant)
```

The above would result in *meals data* along with its *associated restaurant's data*.

Comment: Just exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much @Pavan !